# Slow JSON Code, Triple Loop

Tags: java, json

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can get this JSON to run more quickly?  This contains information for a gradebook containing multiple courses, with each course containing  multiple students, and each student containing multiple assignments.  I knew that using a triple loop might slow things down.  But this is taking over a half an hour to execute.

```
JSONArray courseJSONArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int c = 0; c < 40; c++) {
            JSONObject courseJSONObject = new JSONObject();
            courseJSONObject.put("course name", course.getName());
            courseJSONObject.put("course teacher", course.getTeacher());
            JSONArray studentJSONArray = new JSONArray();
            for(int s = 0; s < 50; s++) {
                JSONObject studentJSONObject = new JSONObject();
                studentJSONObject.put("student name", course.student.getName());
                studentJSONObject.put("student id", course.student.getid());
                studentJSONObject.put("student final grade", course.student.getfinalgrade());
                JSONArray assignmentJSONArray = new JSONArray();
                for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
                    JSONObject assignmentJSONObject = new JSONObject();
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("assignment name", getAssignmentName());
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("category", getAssignmentCategory());
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("date", getAssignmentDate());
                    assignmentJSONObject.put("grade", course.student.getAssignmentGrade());
                    assignmentJSONArray.add( assignmentJSONObject );
                    }
                studentJSONObject.put( "assignments", assignmentJSONArray );
                studentJSONArray.add( studentJSONObject );
                }
            courseJSONObject.put( "students", studentJSONArray );
            courseJSONArray.add( courseJSONObject );
            }
```

Comment: you have 20000 items. That can take some time, but 30 minutes sounds like a lot. Also, I assume this is not the final code, as all items apparently contain the same values?

Comment: Anyway, if you can assert that the time is indeed consumed by jon generating, consider switching to a stream based json library, such as jackson. There being no intermediary object structure would make it much faster

Comment: This is the final code except for the fact that the getters are not the same, as you noticed.  Thus, the values would contain different values.  Also, the code was part of an HTTP request...but I didn't include that code either since I thought that would distract from my main question.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem is not because of the triple loop?

Comment: it does not matter how many loops you have. the important value is how many times you loop through them. In your case, 50*40*100 = 20000. It would be the same if you had only one loop with 20000 iterations.

Comment: You need to start by profiling your code to figure out which methods are taking the most time. For all we know from here, it could be in the getters, or outside of this code altogether. What platform is that running on?

Comment: It's running on Windows 8, Intel Celeron, 2.13 GHz, 4 GB RAM.

Comment: I recommend http://visualvm.java.net/ to profile your app.

Comment: I do want to mention that I did a test run with the same values (instead of using the getters).  That also took over 15 minutes.